# How can I add multiple cards in ListView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I am trying to make a bookmark app and would like to show 3 bookmarks(ex: Google, Apple, Facebook) as default. So I want to add 3 more cards inside the ListView, but it results in error if I try to add other cards. How can I solve this problem? Please help me. Here is the code down below.

```
class _BookmarkListPageState extends State<BookmarkListPage> {

  List<String> bookmarkList = [];
  List<String> bookmarkUrl = [];

  _launchUrl(int index) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(bookmarkUrl[index]);
    if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
      await launchUrl(url);
    } else {
      throw "Could not open $url";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var box = Hive.box(bookmarkBox);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          widget.title,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          child: Container(
            height: 1,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(1),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: bookmarkList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          // delete card if you swipe
          return Dismissible(
            background: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.delete,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onDismissed: (direction) {
              setState(() {
                bookmarkList.removeAt(index);
              });
            },
            key: UniqueKey(),
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  bookmarkList[index],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(bookmarkUrl[index]),
                onTap:() => _launchUrl(index),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: Which part of the code that adds a card to the list?

Comment: *it results in error* is useless. Clearly you got an error message, or you wouldn't know that there was an error, which means that you have that error message text to put in your post. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen. You're asking us for help to solve a problem you're having, and it's in your best interest to provide the details you have available to make it as easy as possible for us to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it like this example

```js
class _BookmarkListPageState extends State<BookmarkListPage> {
  List<String> bookmarkList = ['Google', 'Apple', 'Facebook'];
  List<String> bookmarkUrl = [
    'https://www.google.com',
    'https://www.apple.com',
    'https://www.facebook.com',
  ];

  // your code...
}
```